# Counting number of points in a lattice with bounded sup norm

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, geometry-of-numbers

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For $\bar{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let 
$\| \bar{x} \| = max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \{ |x_i| \}$, i.e. the sup norm. Let $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$
be a successive minima of $\Lambda$ with respect to the sup norm.

I am interested in counting number of points 
$N(U) = \# \{ \bar{x} \in \Lambda : \| \bar{x} \| < U  \}$ when say $\lambda_{j} \leq U < \lambda_{j+1}$. I am expecting some like
$$
\frac{U^j}{\lambda_1 ... \lambda_j}  \ll N(U) \ll \frac{U^{j}}{\lambda_1 ... \lambda_{j}}
$$ 
when $\lambda_{j} \leq U < \lambda_{j+1}$, where the 
implicit constants may depend on $\det (\Lambda)$ and $n$, but not on $\Lambda$ itself.

I would appreciate any assistance, comments, or references. Thank you very much!

PS And I mean the inequalities as they are. Thank you!

Comment: Since you were asking about the $j$-volume of the parallelopiped $\mathcal P$ spanned by $v_1,\ldots,v_j$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you might find the following formula interesting. Let $A$ be the $n$-by-$j$ matrix the contains the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_j$ as the columns. Let $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_k$ denote all of the $j$-by-$j$ minors of $A$, so $k=\binom{n}{j}$. Then $\operatorname{Vol}(\mathcal P)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \det(B_i)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectation is correct. Let $\lambda_{j} \leq U < \lambda_{j+1}$. There are independent lattice vectors $v_1,\dots,v_j\in\Lambda$ such that $\|v_i\|=\lambda_i$ for $1\leq i\leq j$.

Consider the linear combinations
$ c_1v_1+\dots +c_j v_j\in\Lambda$ with integral coefficients $c_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $|c_i|\leq U/(2n\lambda_i)$. Their sup-norms are $\leq U/2<U$, and their number is $\gg_n U^j/(\lambda_1\dots\lambda_j)$. This proves the lower bound.

Now consider the subspace $V_j=\mathbb{R}v_1+\dots+\mathbb{R}v_j$ equipped with the $j$-volume coming from the euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. an orthonormal basis in $V_j$ spans a $j$-cube of $j$-volume $1$. Then, $\Lambda_j=\Lambda\cap V_j$ is a lattice in $V_j$ with successive minima $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_j$, hence by [Minkowski's second theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_second_theorem) its fundamental parallelepiped $P_j$ has $j$-volume
$$\text{vol}_j(P_j)\geq 2^{-j}\cdot\lambda_1\dots\lambda_j\cdot\text{vol}_j(B_j),$$
where $B_j=\{ \bar{x} \in V_j : \| \bar{x} \| \leq 1  \}.$
The sup-norm is majorized by the euclidean norm, hence $B_j$ contains a euclidean $j$-ball of radius $1$, which shows that $\text{vol}_j(P_j)\gg_j \lambda_1\dots\lambda_j$.
On the other hand,
$$\{ \bar{x} \in \Lambda : \| \bar{x} \| < U  \}=\{ \bar{x} \in \Lambda_j : \| \bar{x} \| < U  \},$$ 
whence the translates of $P_j$ by the elements of this set are pairwise disjoint and they all lie in $\{ \bar{x} \in V_j : \| \bar{x} \| < (j+1)U  \}$ whose $j$-volume is $\ll_j U^j$. This proves the upper bound.

**Remark.** The above argument was enhanced and corrected by the OP's comments, for which I am grateful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Would you happen to know a good reference for geometry of numbers? as I am not too familiar with lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are not of full rank, and $j$-volumes. Thank you!

Comment: @SJY: You don't need any reference. The vectors $v_i$ for $1\leq i\leq j$ are linearly independent, hence they generate a full rank lattice in the vector space $V$. The $j$-volume simply means the volume on $V$ induced by the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Perhaps you might keep in mind that the sup-norm and the Euclidean norm are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely $\|v\|_\infty\leq\|v\|_2\leq \sqrt{n}\|v\|_\infty$. Good books on the geometry of numbers is the one by Gruber-Lekkerkerker and the one by Cassels. If you like my answer, accept it officially so that it turns green.

Comment: Thank you! (I like the answer very much, I just wanted to clarify couple things before I hit the button :) ). Could you possibly explain me how to compute the $j$-volume of the fundamental parallelepiped of the above lattice by any chance? I am only familiar with the case when I have $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$...

Comment: You don't have to calculate the $j$-volume of the fundamental parallelepiped for the above proof. However, if you want to calculate it, then simply orthogonalize the basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_j\}$ to an orthogonal basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_j\}$, and then the $j$-volume in question is $\prod_i|w_i|$. Alternately, express each $v_i$ $(1\leq i\leq j)$ in an orthonormal basis, and form a $j\times j$ determinant out of the $j$ coefficient vectors. The $j$-volume is the absolute value of this determinant.

Comment: Note that this is just how one calculates the volume of the fundamental parallelepiped in $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^j$. A $j$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just a copy of $\mathbb{R}^j$.

Comment: In my previous comment $|w_i|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of $w_i$, not its sup-norm.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very helpful comments! I greatly appreciate it. Could you possibly explain me what you mean by I don't have to calculate $j$-volume for the proof? (I am a bit confused because you used $j$-volumes in the proof...)

Comment: @SJY: I added more detail, I hope it clarifies.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Would it be possible that you give me some sort of hint/short explanation why the translates of Pj by the elements of $\{\bar{x} \in \Gamma : \| \bar{x} \| <U\}$ are pairwise disjoint by any chance? I have been stuck on this for a while... (You had been so helpful already! and sorry to bother you again!)

Comment: The set $\{\bar{x} \in \Gamma : \| \bar{x} \| <U\}$ is the same as $\{\bar{x} \in \Lambda_j : \| \bar{x} \| <U\}$, since $U<\lambda_{j+1}$. Hence the translates of $P_j$ by the elements of this set are pairwise disjoint (by the definition of $P_j$).

Comment: Right. That's exactly where I was having trouble with. I know every point in $\{ \bar{x} \in \Gamma : \| \bar{x} \| < U  \}$ has to be a linear combination of $v_1, ..., v_j$ but I am having trouble showing that the coefficients have to be integers...

Comment: @SJY: You are right, I should have considered $\Lambda\cap V_j$ instead of the sublattice spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_j$. I rewrote my post, have a look! I hope everything is correct now.

Comment: Thank you very very much! Everything makes sense now! :D

Comment: I was wondering if you could possibly answer one of my questions again. In the final part of the argument, we use the fact that $Vol_j( \cup (\bar{p} + P_j) ) \leq Vol_j( \{ \bar{x} \in V_j:  \| \bar{x}\| < (j+1) U \} )$
where the union is distinct over $\bar{p} \in \{ \bar{x} \in \Lambda:  \| \bar{x}\| < U \}$.
How do I know that if $E_1 \subseteq E_2$, then $Vol_j(E_1) \leq Vol_j(E_2)$?

Is it because it corresponds to Lebesgue measure? I was confused about this because I only know
that the $j$ volume of the parallelpiped is this value assigned by determinants...

Comment: @SJY: The $j$-volume is the Lebesgue measure on the underlying $j$-dimensional subspace. I called it $j$-volume to distinguish it from the Lebesgue measure on the full space.

Comment: In order to define Lebesgue measure we need boxes and volume of those boxes. When you say the Lebesgue measure on $V_j = \mathbb{R}v_1 + ... + \mathbb{R} v_j$, do we use a box of the form  $B = \{a_1 v_1 + ... + a_j v_j : a_l \in [r_l, t_l] \ (1 \leq l \leq j) \}$ and what would $Vol_j(B)$ be? Thank you so much again for your help.

Comment: @SJY: The volume of $B$ is $\prod_{l=1}^j(t_l-r_l)$ times $Vol_j(B')$, where $B'=[0,1]v_1+\dots+[0,1]v_j$ is the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_j$. In order to find $Vol_j(B')$, follow my comment of Apr 5 at 3:42. At any rate, you can read about the Lebesgue measure in many textbooks, e.g. in Rudin: Real and complex analysis.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for all of your help!! You had been so helpful and I really appreciate it!! I am giving extra points just as my token of appreciation. I hope that's ok!